# Specific .htaccess redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use mobile redirection code:

```
HTACCESS MOBILE SITE REDIRECTION CODE

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|blackberry|brew|cldc|docomo|htc|j2me|micromax|lg|midp|mot|motorola|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|opera.mini|palm|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windows.ce) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url1 [R=302,L]
```

With this code my entire site redirect the mobile visitors to url1.
So, I want to keep that redirection as is it, but to have different redirection for one or more specific urls from my site e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/sample.htm` to redirect visitors to url2, while the rest of the site to redirect visitors to url1.

Thank you.

Comment: .htaccess files are parsed from  top to bottom, so as long as your rule to redirect from `sample.htm` to `url2` is before the one you've already got, you shouldn't have any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mobile|android|blackberry|brew|cldc|docomo|htc|j2me|micromax|lg|midp|mot|motorola|netfront|nokia|obigo|openweb|opera.mini|palm|psp|samsung|sanyo|sch|sonyericsson|symbian|symbos|teleca|up.browser|vodafone|wap|webos|windows.ce) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_MOBILE:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_MOBILE} 1
RewriteRule ^sample\.htm/?$ url2 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_MOBILE} 1
RewriteRule (?!^url2/?$)^.*$ url1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: That is great to know, pls accept the answer whenever you can.